# SPFX Development environment trouble, has anyone seen lookups.flatmap error?

Tags: spfx

I recently replaced my workstation and started to begin test the new environment, however I have not been able to successfully run: yo@microsofst/sharepoint to begin scaffolding. below is what I have set up.

Node v 10.24.1 | NPM v 6.14.12

```
--- 
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0
+-- @pnp/generator-spfx@1.16.1
+-- gulp@4.0.2
`-- yo@3.1.1
---
```

Running yo doctor

```
Running sanity checks on your system
√ No .bowerrc file in home directory
√ Global configuration file is valid
√ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
√ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
√ Node.js version
√ npm version
√ yo version

Everything looks all right!
```

running yo

```
TypeError: lookups.flatMap is not a function
at Environment.resolver.lookup enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not alone. [Same question is asked here this morning](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293105/unable-to-setup-sharepoint-framework-dev-environment). I had the same error this morning when I was setting up a new environment:

[image]

For some reason, downgrading yeoman from 4.0.0 to 3.1.1 version fixed the issue. But it looks like your package versions are identical:

```
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0
+-- @pnp/generator-spfx@1.16.1
+-- gulp@4.0.2
+-- npm@6.14.11
`-- yo@3.1.1
```

Perhaps, you can also try 10.24.0 nodejs instead of 10.24.1.